# Usando esta regra, como faço para excluir todas as (Descriptions) da ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_especialidades);


    Integer[] imgid={
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white,
            R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white, R.drawable.ic_plus_white};


    String[] atividades = new String[]{"Acupuntura", "Alergia e Imunologia", "Anestesiologia",
            "Angiologia", "Angiorradiologia e Cirurgia Endovascular", "Cancerologia",
            "Cardiologia", "Cardiologia Pediátrica", "Cirurgia Cardiovascular", "Cirurgia da Cabeça e Pescoço",
            "Cirurgia do Aparelho Digestivo", "Cirurgia do Trauma", "Cirurgia Geral", "Cirurgia Pediátrica", "Cirurgia Plástica",
            "Cirurgia Torácica", "Cirurgia Vascular", "Cirurgião Dentista", "Clínica Médica", "Coloproctologia", "Dermatologia",
            "Ecocardiografia", "Eletrofisiologia Clínica Invasiva", "Endocrinologia", "Endoscopia", "Endoscopia Digestiva",
            "Ergometria", "Fisioterapeuta", "Gastroenterologia", "Gastroenterologia Pediátrica", "Genética Médica",
            "Geriatria", "Ginecologia e Obstetrícia", "Hematologia e Hemoterapia", "Hematologia e Hemoterapia Pediátrica",
            "Hemodinâmica e Cardiologia Intervencionista", "Hepatologia", "Infectologia", "Instrumentador", "Mastologia",
            "Medicina de Urgência", "Medicina Esportiva", "Medicina fetal", "Medicina Física e Reabilitação", "Medicina Intensiva",
            "Medicina Intensiva Pediátrica", "Medicina Nuclear", "Nefrologia", "Nefrologia Pediátrica", "Neurocirurgia",
            "Neurofisiologia Clínica", "Neurologia", "Neurorradiologia", "Nutrição Parenteral e Enteral", "Nutrologia",
            "Oftalmologia", "Ortopedia e Traumatologia", "Otorrinolaringologia", "Patologia", "Patologia Clínica/Medicina Laboratorial",
            "Pediatria", "Pneumologia", "Pneumologia Pediátrica", "Psiquiatria", "Radiologia e Diagnóstico por Imagem",
            "Radiologia Intervencionista e Angiorradiologia", "Reprodução Humana", "Reumatologia", "Urologia"};





    CustomListAdapter adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, atividades, imgid);

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(chamaAtividades(this));
}

public AdapterView.OnItemClickListener chamaAtividades(final Context context){
    return (new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent;
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    intent = new Intent(context, ListaActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent = new Intent(context, AlergiaImunologiaActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

CustomListAdapter:

public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]);
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return rowView;

};
```

}

Comment: Julgo que conseguirá fazer isso sozinho se olhar para o `xml`, que define o item da lista e para o `adpater`.

Comment: Este é o xml dele.

Comment: Não é esse. Poste o código da classe *CustomListAdapter*

Comment: Achei o problema amigo Ramaral, mais uma vez muito obrigado.